# The afterRender template call seems to be executed as a computedObservables. Why and how to fix it?

Tags: templates, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

So this question follows on from my previous question [Under what conditions does a Knockout native template re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241540/under-what-conditions-does-a-knockout-native-template-re-render)

After some investigation, it seems that if a template defines an `afterRender` function and that `afterRender` function references a part model then, if that part of the model is subsequently altered, the `afterRender` function is called again.

This behaviour seems similar to `computedObservables` (aka `dependentObservables`) where knockout tracks which parts of the model it depends on and then re-runs the `computedObservables` whenever one of the values it depends on changes.

To demonstrate this I have written a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/nczCt/1/

As expected the afterRender function is called when the view is rendered. However, if you click the checkbox, the afterRender function is run again as it uses `viewModel.selectedPet().pet().IsHappy()`

This does not make sense to me. So my question is:

- **Is this a bug that the `afterRender` function is being re-run?**
- **How can I ensure that the `afterRender` function is only run once?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout uses a computed observable to wrap the execution of the bindings on an element.  This is how the bindings are triggered again when a dependency changes (this [link](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html) might help explain further.

Currently, the `afterRender` code is not excluded from adding to these dependencies.  If this is not desirable for your scenario, then there are a couple of ways to prevent it.

- run your code in a `setTimeout`: like http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/nczCt/2/
- wrap your code in its own computed observable that you immediately dispose like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/nczCt/3/  (I would do this for now to avoid the setTimeout)
- In KO 2.2 you will be able to use the new `peek` function on observables that allows you to get the value without creating a dependency.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks, Ryan. Looking forward to KO 2.2.